# Access ViewPager fragment views

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with 2 fragment pages inside it. Now i want to access the views (textview,buttons) from the first fragment page but everytime Iam getting Nullpointer exception
check out my code

Fragment i want to access its views:

```
    public class ListPagerFragment extends Fragment
    {
    ListView listview;
    TextView text;
    private ViewPager pager;

    public static ListPagerFragment newInstance(int message)
    {
        ListPagerFragment f = new ListPagerFragment();
        // pass the text message received from main activity into a bundle to be
        // delivered to the new fragment
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
        bdl.putInt("num", message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_pager_fragment, container, false);
        return v;
    }
    public void fillList(Nameslist list)
    {       
        listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        if (listview == null)
            System.out.println("listview null"); //this should not be null but
//it is thus the nullpointerexception
        if (listview.getAdapter() == null)
        {
            MyListAdapter listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, list.getVenues());
            listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
        else
        {
            ((MyListAdapter) listview.getAdapter()).updateAdapter(list.getnames());
        } 

    }
```

PagerAdapter code

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private int mCount = 1;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
        case 1:
            return ResultsPagerFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
        return ListPagerFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mCount;
    }
}
```

and main finally activity code

```
private ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}
```

and later somewhere in the activity i have the code that should trigger the fillList from Fragment to do the job

```
Fragment frag = pagerAdapter.getItem(0); //this should give me the Fragment i want right?
        ((ListPagerFragment)frag).fillList(result);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure your function is called after `onCreateView()`? before you'll not have a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it seems like the problem was in my custom FragmentStatePagerAdapter
All I had to do is create the fragments when activity is created and put them into an ArrayList which it will be later passed to MyPagerAdapter

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        frags = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        frags.add(ListPagerFragment.newInstance(0));
        frags.add(ResultsPagerFragment.newInstance(1));

        pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),frags);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    }
```

And then modify the MyPagerAdapter like so:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> frags)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = frags;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {   
        return fragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

kind of silly isn't it? I don't understand the point but it worked

Comment: Any idea with mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907625/why-is-accessing-textview-of-a-fragment-inside-activity-throwing-an-error

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you are trying to use the views from your Activity, before your ListPagerFragment.onCreateView() has inflated your xml layout. Move what's inside your onCreate() and some code of fillList() to onCreateView(), something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_pager_fragment, container, false);

    listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    return v;
}
```

After your fragments onCreateView() has inflated the view, you can try to fill it.

And don't forget to clear your view references and unregister your listview listener(if you set one) in onDestroyView() to avoid memory leaks, e.g.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(null);
    ...
    listview = null;
}
```

read about the fragment's lifecycle --> [Fragment's Lifefycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle)

Comment: Thanks I have already considered that possibility. I am pretty sure I don't take any action before the fragment is created. I tried your code but no luck :/